# Erro: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Tags: r

Estou tentando encapsular um código em funções mas no processo acontece o tal erro:

> object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Porém não consigo achar o porquê. Segue o código funcionando:

```
h = (b-a)/n

B = array(0,c(n-1,n-1)) #gera Matriz (n-1)x(n-1) = {0}

x = array(0,c(n-1)) #gera vetor x = {0}

for(i in 1:(n-1))
{ 
    x[i] = a+i*h
}

####Gera a Matriz####

for (i in 1:(n-1)) #preenche a diagonal principal com a expressao: 2+(h^2)*q(x)
{
    B[i,i] = 2+(h^2)*q 
}

for (i in 1:(n-2)) #preenche as diagonais abaixo/acima com -1. Os demais elementos permanecem 0
{
    B[i+1,i]=-1
    B[i,i+1]=-1
}

####Gera o Vetor de Termos Independentes####    

v_h = array(0,c(n-1,1)) #gera vetor v_h = {0}

for (i in 1:(n-1)) #preenche o vetor v_h com a expressao: -(h^2)*r(x[i])
{
    v_h[i,1]=-(h^2)*r(x[i])
}
v_h[1,1]=v_h[1,1] + alpha #primeiro termo : -(h^2)*r(x[i]) + alpha
v_h[n-1,1]=v_h[n-1,1] + beta #ultimo termo : -(h^2)*r(x[i]) + alpha

####Metodo de Gauss####
aux = 0
solucao = array(0,c(n-1,1)) #gera o vetor solucao obtido por Gauss

start.time <- Sys.time() #inicia contagem do tempo

for (j in 1:(n-2)) # escalona a Matriz B
{
    if (B[j,j] == 0)
    {
        for (k in 1:(n-1))
        {
            if (B[k,j] != 0)
            {
                aux = B[j,j]
                B[j,j] = B[k,j]         
                B[k,j] = aux
            }
        }
    }
    for (i in (j+1):(n-1))
    {
        m = ((-1)*B[i,j])/B[j,j]
        for(k in j:(n-1))
        {
            B[i,k]=B[i,k]+(m*B[j,k])
        }
        v_h[i,1]= v_h[i,1]+(m*v_h[j,1]) 
    }

}

solucao[n-1] = v_h[n-1]/B[n-1,n-1]

for(i in (n-2):1) # resolução do sistema triangular
{
    solucao[i] = v_h[i]
    for(j in (i+1):(n-1))
    {
        solucao[i]=(solucao[i])-(B[i,j]*solucao[j])
    }
    solucao[i]=(solucao[i]/B[i,i])
}

end.time <- Sys.time()
time.taken <- end.time - start.time
time.taken #tempo obtido

solve (B,v_h) #solucao obtida pelo R

solucao #solucao obtida pelo metodo de Gauss
```

Agora segue a tentativa de encapsulamento:

```
GeraMatriz = function(n,a,b,q) 
{

    h = (b-a)/n

    B = array(0,c(n-1,n-1)) #gera Matriz (n-1)x(n-1) = {0}
    x = array(0,c(n-1)) #gera vetor x = {0}

    for(i in 1:(n-1))
    { 
        x[i] = a+i*h
    }

    for (i in 1:(n-1)) #preenche a diagonal principal com a expressao: 2+(h^2)*q(x)
    {
        B[i,i] = 2+(h^2)*q 
    }

    for (i in 1:(n-2)) #preenche as diagonais abaixo/acima com -1. Os demais elementos permanecem 0
    {
        B[i+1,i]=-1
        B[i,i+1]=-1
    }
    return (B)
}

####

GeraVh = function(n,a,b,y,r)
{   

    h = (b-a)/n

    x = array(0,c(n-1)) #gera vetor x = {0}

    for(i in 1:(n-1))
    { 
        x[i] = a+i*h
    }

    alpha = y(a)
    beta = y(b)

    v_h = array(0,c(n-1,1)) #gera vetor v_h = {0}

    for (i in 1:(n-1)) #preenche o vetor v_h com a expressao: -(h^2)*r(x[i])
    {
        v_h[i,1]=-(h^2)*r(x[i])
    }
    v_h[1,1]=v_h[1,1] + alpha #primeiro termo : -(h^2)*r(x[i]) + alpha
    v_h[n-1,1]=v_h[n-1,1] + beta #ultimo termo : -(h^2)*r(x[i]) + alpha

    return(v_h)
}

####

Gauss = function(n,a,b,y,q,r)
{

    GeraMatriz(n,a,b,q)
    GeraVh(n,a,b,y,r)

    aux = 0

    solucao = array(0,c(n-1,1)) #gera o vetor solucao obtido por Gauss

    start.time <- Sys.time() #inicia contagem do tempo

    for (j in 1:(n-2)) # escalona a Matriz B
    {
        if (B[j,j] == 0)
        {
            for (k in 1:(n-1))
            {
                if (B[k,j] != 0)
                {
                    aux = B[j,j]
                    B[j,j] = B[k,j]         
                    B[k,j] = aux
                }
            }
        }
        for (i in (j+1):(n-1))
        {
            m = ((-1)*B[i,j])/B[j,j]
                for(k in j:(n-1))
            {
                        B[i,k]=B[i,k]+(m*B[j,k])
                }
                v_h[i,1]= v_h[i,1]+(m*v_h[j,1]) 
        }

    }

    solucao[n-1] = v_h[n-1]/B[n-1,n-1]

    for(i in (n-2):1) # resolução do sistema triangular
    {
        solucao[i] = v_h[i]
        for(j in (i+1):(n-1))
        {
            solucao[i]=(solucao[i])-(B[i,j]*solucao[j])
        }
        solucao[i]=(solucao[i]/B[i,i])
    }

    end.time <- Sys.time()
    time.taken <- end.time - start.time
    time.taken #tempo obtido

    solve (B,v_h) #solucao obtida pelo R

    solucao #solucao obtida pelo metodo de Gauss

}
```

Após o inserimento dos parâmetros,

```
y = function(x){return((exp(sqrt(2)*x))+(exp(-sqrt(2)*x))+((2/27)*sin(4*x))-((1/6)*x*cos(4*x)))} 

r = function(x){return(3*x*cos(4*x))} 

a = 0 

b = 1 

q = 2 

n = 10
```

o console me retorna o seguinte erro:

> Gauss(n,a,b,y,q,r) Error in v_h[i, 1] : object of type 'closure' is
>   not subsettable

O que pode ser feito?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As funções no R funcionam um pouco diferente do que você deve estar acostumado. 
No seu caso basta mudar as duas primeiras linahs da função `Gauss` por:

```
B <- GeraMatriz(n,a,b,q)
v_h <- GeraVh(n,a,b,y,r)
```

No `R` as funções não compartilham escopo. Todos os objetos criados dentro de uma função coletados pelo `gc` depois que a função terminou de rodar (a não ser que tenham sido criados com `<<-`). Desse modo, você sempre precisa atribuir o resultado de uma função ao valor de uma variável na próxima função.

O erro padrão neste caso deveria ser:

> `Error: object 'v_h' not found`

Seria muito mais fácil de saber o que aconteceu. O problema é que você deve ter alguma função chamda `v_h` definida no seu ambiente global.

Veja por exemplo o que acontece quando você tenta obter elementos da função:

```
> v_h <- function(x){
+   return(x)
+ }
> v_h[1,1]
Error in v_h[1, 1] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

Isso acontece porque as funções no R primeiro procuram objetos dentro do seu *environment* e recursivamente dentro de seu *environment* pai. Por exemplo:

```
> x <- 1
> funcao <- function(a){
+   return(x*2)
+ }
> funcao(10)
[1] 2
```

Mesmo sem `x` estar declarado dentro do escopo da `funcao` ele é encontrado e calculado, pois o R procura variáveis com nome `x` no ambiente pai.

Para conseguir driblar esses problemas, é bom de vez em quando excluir todos os objetos do ambiente global. Se você tivesse feito isso teria recebido o erro que indicaria mais claramente o problema. Para excluir todos os objetos é só usar: `rm(list = ls())`.